# Why is $gH=H=Hg$ trivial for $g\in H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In nearly all proofs for the "subgroup of index 2 is normal" statement, there is a sentence that reads more or less: if $g\in H\subseteq G$ then
$$gH=H=Hg,$$
but why is this trivial?
In particular, it is not clear to me why
$$\{gh: h\in H\} = \{h'g: h\in H\}$$
holds or even that they have the same cardinality (in general, i.e., if $g$ is not neutral of course). Am I just looking at the wrong representation to see this relationship? Or am I missing something in this representation?

Comment: Hint: If $g\in H$, then $g^{-1}$ is also in $H$.

Comment: @AlexS what does this imply, besides $e\in gH$ and $e\in Hg$?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $g\in H$. Then $g^{-1}$ is also in $H$. Therefore, if $h\in H$, $k=g^{-1}h\in H$, so $gk=g(g^{-1}h)=h\in gH$. Therefore, $H\subset gH$. On the other hand, an arbitrary element $k\in gH$ has the form $gh$ for some $h\in H$. Since both $g$ and $h$ are in $H$, $k\in H$. Therefore $gH\subset H$. We conclude that $gH=H$. A symmetric argument shows $Hg=H$, completing the proof.